# using jquery dialog perform form submit and validation in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Hi I had a form and a partial view. The partial view represents the file upload content, it contains file name textbox and file input. On the form there is a button, when clicked, it loads this partial view into jquery dialog with submit and cancel button. After use clicks submit button, it simply called $("#myform").submit.  Everything works fine, but I want to perform mvc validation, if the document name is empty, I'd like to keep the dialog still open and display the errors in the ValidationSummary area. Can someone give me some idea how to achieve this

Thanks

Here is my jquery dialog box code

```
   submitDialog:function(url,title,event,target,frm,onLoadCallBack){
    event.preventDefault();
    $url = url;
    $title = title;
    var $dialog = $(target);
    $dialog.empty();
    $dialog
        .load($url,onLoadCallBack)            
        .dialog({
            bgiframe: true,
            title: $title,
            height: 200,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,                  
        }); 
    $dialog
        .dialog("option", "buttons", {
            "Submit":function(){
                var dlg = $(this);
                var $frm = $(frm);
                $frm.submit();
        },
        "Cancel": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $(this).empty();
        }    

    });
   $dialog.dialog('open');

 }
```

This is my partial view

```
@model MVCWeb.Models.UploadDocBaseModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Document Upload";
}

<h3>Documents</h3>
   @using (Html.BeginForm(MVC.Order.SaveOrderDoc(Model), FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =             "multipart/form-data", Id = "frmDocUpload" } ))
  {
   @Html.ValidationSummary() 
   <fieldset>        
      <ol>
        <li class="clearfix">
            <label class="fixed-width-label medium">Document Name</label>
            @Html.TextBox("docName", "", new { @class = "text-field medium" })
        </li>
        <li class="clearfix">
            <label class="fixed-width-label medium">Upload</label>
            <input type="file" id="docFile" name="fileUpload" />
        </li>          
       </ol>
   </fieldset>
  }
```

My Controller

```
        public virtual ActionResult DocumentUpload(long idOrder)
    {
        UploadDocBaseModel docModel = new UploadDocBaseModel { IdParent = idOrder };
        //return PartialView("",docModel);
        return PartialView(Views._OrderDocUpload, docModel);
    }

    public virtual ActionResult SaveOrderDoc(UploadDocBaseModel model)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {

        }

        return PartialView(Views._OrderDocUpload, model);
    }
```

Comment: bdparrish didn't answer the question, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

The file upload input will be read by jQuery as a Textbox input so you can do ...

```
var filenamePath = ('#mytextboxinputforfile').val() // returns the filename in the textbox
if (filenamePath == '') {
    // show error in validation summary.  you can get this by looking at the 
    // page source to see what the validation summary id is and set the text.
}
```

Comment: What I expect to have a callback on the submit event. because my controller will rebind the view and error state is already there, cause I used data annotation, so I'd like to just redisplay that.

Comment: well that is not what you were originally asking, why are you validating in jquery before posting but want to just post either way and display the error?  can i see your View code?  you might just need the <%: Html.ValidationSummary() %> added into the page code.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain very well. What I expect to have a callback on the submit event. Since my controller will rebind and return the partial view and error state is already there(I used data annotation), so I'd like to just redisplay that in the dialog. What happened now when I returned the partial view, it will redisplay the form with error but in a new page not in the jquery dialog, so I lose the whole page content. I will append the rest of my code in the question

Comment: so you actually have to make an $.ajax call and send the form data that way.  in the success function of the $.ajax call you will get the response which should be the HTML and set the html of your dialog box.  the way you have it now, the submit function will call a postback to the server and act like a normal submit that will reload the page with the changes.

Comment: No I can't, coz I am doing the file upload, not simple page ajax post.